# Show that the matrix $(a_{j,k})_{j,k\in \mathbb{N}}$ induces a bounded operator on $\ell^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a matrix $(a_{j,k})_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by:

$ a_{j,k} = \dfrac{1 -e^{-jk}}{jk + 1}$

and I need to show that this induces a bounded operator on $\ell^2$. I'm pretty sure Schur's test is inconclusive. So my guess is to use the Hilber-Schmidt test, which states that if,

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|\dfrac{1 -e^{-jk}}{jk + 1}\right|^2 < \infty$, then $(a_{j,k})$ induces a bounded operator.

However, I'm not sure how to do this summation - can anyone give me a hint?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\frac{1-e^{-jk}}{jk+1}\right| < \frac{1}{jk}$$

so

$$\sum_{j,k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1-e^{-jk}}{jk+1}\right|^2 < \sum_{j,k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2k^2} = \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}\right)^2 < \infty$$

since $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2} =  \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac{1-e^{-jk}}{jk+1}|^2 \leq \frac{1}{j^2k^2}$ for large $j,k$.